# Pandas dataframe apply speed issues - is there another way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, lookup

I've got a dataframe telephone calls, and a dataframe of orders - i'm trying to write the order details to the telephone dataframe IF the order was created around about the same time AND the account numbers match.

Currently i'm pandas "apply" along with a function i've written but its SLOW. It appears to be iterating through every record and its taking forever.

I would juse join or merge as they are lightening quick, but I cant seem to put any real form of conditional logic in there? And i want to specify that the order is created within 5 minutes of the call time, Any suggestions?

My current method is below (go easy on me - i'm still learning)

## function

```
def get_order_from_call_time_and_person(row):

    row = pd.Series(row)
    mn = row["MINUTE"]
    hr = row["HOUR"]    
    dy = row["DAY"]
    mt = row["MONTH"]
    yr = row["YEAR"]
    ac = row["oprano"]

    mnFrom = mn
    mnTo = mn
    hrFrom = hr
    hrTo = hr
    mnIN = 0
    mnFrom = (mn - 5)
    mnTo = (mn + 5)
    hrFrom = hr
    hrTo = hr
    if mnFrom < 0:
        mnFrom = (mn-5)+60
        hrFrom = hr-1
    if mnTo > 60:
        mnTo = mnTo-60
        hrTo =hr+1
    if mnFrom > mnTo:
        mnIN = mnFrom
        mnFrom = mnTo
        mnTo = mnIN

    order1 = orders_df[(orders_df["hour_created"].between(hrFrom,hrTo)) &
          (orders_df["day_created"] == int(dy)) & 
          (orders_df["month_created"] == int(mt)) & 
          (orders_df["year_created"] == int(yr)) & 
          (orders_df["slaccount"] == str(ac))]

    try:

        value = order1["value"].iloc[0]
        quoteno = order1["quoteno"].iloc[0]
        cost = order1["costvalue"].iloc[0]
        orderno = order1["ordernumber"].iloc[0]
        if orderno == "" or orderno == "NAN":
            orderno = "none"
        margin = order1["value"].iloc[0] - order1["costvalue"].iloc[0]
        minute_confirmed = order1["minute_confirmed"].iloc[0]
        hour_confirmed = order1["hour_confirmed"].iloc[0]
        day_confirmed = order1["day_confirmed"].iloc[0]
        month_confirmed = order1["month_confirmed"].iloc[0]
        year_confirmed = order1["year_confirmed"].iloc[0]
        print( "OK")
        return pd.Series((value, margin, cost, int(quoteno), orderno , minute_confirmed, hour_confirmed, day_confirmed, month_confirmed, year_confirmed))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Not Found")
        return pd.Series(("none", "none" , "none", "none", "none","none", "none" , "none", "none", "none"))
```

## calling code to check orders against call logs.

```
df[['value', 'margin','cost','quote_no','order_no','minute_confirmed','hour_confirmed','day_confirmed','month_confirmed',"year_confirmed"]] = df[["MINUTE","HOUR","DAY","MONTH","YEAR","oprano"]].apply(lambda x : get_order_from_call_time_and_person(x),axis=1)
```

[image: example data]

run this to get the HTML table version of the data

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dwindows-125=
2">
<meta name=3DProgId content=3DExcel.Sheet>
<meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Excel 15">
<link id=3DMain-File rel=3DMain-File href=3D"../dataex.htm">
<link rel=3DFile-List href=3Dfilelist.xml>
<![if IE]>
<base href=3D"file:///C:/0E4B9118/dataex_files/sheet001.htm"
id=3D"webarch_temp_base_tag">
<![endif]>
<link rel=3DStylesheet href=3Dstylesheet.css>
<style>
<!--table
 {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
 mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
@page
 {margin:.75in .7in .75in .7in;
 mso-header-margin:.3in;
 mso-footer-margin:.3in;}
-->
</style>
<![if !supportTabStrip]><script language=3D"JavaScript">
<!--
function fnUpdateTabs()
 {
  if (parent.window.g_iIEVer>=3D4) {
   if (parent.document.readyState=3D=3D"complete"
    && parent.frames['frTabs'].document.readyState=3D=3D"complete")
   parent.fnSetActiveSheet(0);
  else
   window.setTimeout("fnUpdateTabs();",150);
 }
}

if (window.name!=3D"frSheet")
 window.location.replace("../dataex.htm");
else
 fnUpdateTabs();
//-->
</script>
<![endif]>
</head>

<body link=3D"#0563C1" vlink=3D"#954F72" class=3Dxl65>

<table border=3D0 cellpadding=3D0 cellspacing=3D0 width=3D1922 style=3D'bor=
der-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:1445pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D119 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-=
alt:4352;
 width:89pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D69 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2523;
 width:52pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D82 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2998;
 width:62pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D70 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2560;
 width:53pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D53 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:1938;
 width:40pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D70 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2560;
 width:53pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D62 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2267;
 width:47pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D82 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2998;
 width:62pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D69 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2523;
 width:52pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D63 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2304;
 width:47pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D83 span=3D2 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;ms=
o-width-alt:
 3035;width:62pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D95 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:3474;
 width:71pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D78 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:2852;
 width:59pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D84 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-a=
lt:3072;
 width:63pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D98 span=3D2 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;ms=
o-width-alt:
 3584;width:74pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D109 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-=
alt:3986;
 width:82pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D167 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-=
alt:6107;
 width:125pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D112 span=3D2 style=3D'mso-width-source:userset;m=
so-width-alt:
 4096;width:84pt'>
 <col class=3Dxl65 width=3D64 style=3D'width:48pt'>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl65 width=3D119 style=3D'height:15.0pt;width:89p=
t'>CALL DATA</td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D69 style=3D'width:52pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D82 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D70 style=3D'width:53pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D53 style=3D'width:40pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D70 style=3D'width:53pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D62 style=3D'width:47pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D82 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D69 style=3D'width:52pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D63 style=3D'width:47pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D83 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D83 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D95 style=3D'width:71pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D78 style=3D'width:59pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D84 style=3D'width:63pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D98 style=3D'width:74pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D98 style=3D'width:74pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D109 style=3D'width:82pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D167 style=3D'width:125pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D112 style=3D'width:84pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D112 style=3D'width:84pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65 width=3D64 style=3D'width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl65 style=3D'height:15.0pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl66 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>CALLDATEANDTIME</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>INITIAL</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>CALLTYPE</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>CALLFROM</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>CALLTO</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>RING</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>TALK</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>PHONE</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>DATE</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>DAYNAME</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>DAY</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>MONTH</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>YEAR</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>MINUTE</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>HOUR</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>INEXTNAME</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>OUTEXTNAME</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>divno</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>divname</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>oprano</td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl67 style=3D'height:15.0pt;border-top:none;box-s=
izing: border-box;
  max-width:none'>16/09/2019 10:18</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>Y</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>2</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>4</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>230</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>7</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>10</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>1618343361</td>
  <td class=3Dxl69 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>16/09/2019</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>Monday</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>1</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>9</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>2019</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>18</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>10</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>SJ</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>none</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>23351</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>World Wide Fancy Good LTD</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>WFG1</td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl70 style=3D'height:15.0pt;border-top:none;box-s=
izing: border-box;
  max-width:none'>16/09/2019 12:06</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>Y</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>1</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>228</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>12</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>-5</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>103</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>7901976152</td>
  <td class=3Dxl72 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>16/09/2019</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>Monday</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>2</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>9</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>2019</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>6</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>12</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>none</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>Robby</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>55503</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>Handy Hardware</td>
  <td class=3Dxl71 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>HHA1</td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl65 style=3D'height:15.0pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl65 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>ORDER DATA</td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl65 style=3D'height:15.0pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl66 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>quoteno</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>quotedate</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>ammenddate</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>orderdate</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>value</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>opco_code</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>costvalue</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>ordernumber</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>orderedby</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>slaccount</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>year_created</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>month_create<span style=3D'di=
splay:
  none'>d</span></td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>day_created</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>hour_created</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>minute_create<span style=3D'd=
isplay:
  none'>d</span></td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>year_confirmed</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>month_confirme<span style=3D'=
display:
  none'>d</span></td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>day_confirmed</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>hour_confirmed</td>
  <td class=3Dxl66 style=3D'border-left:none'>minute_confirmed</td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl68 style=3D'height:15.0pt;border-top:none;box-s=
izing: border-box;
  max-width:none'>1508</td>
  <td class=3Dxl69 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>11/06/2013</td>
  <td class=3Dxl69 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>12/06/2013</td>
  <td class=3Dxl69 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>11/06/2013</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>36.36</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>L</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>16.77</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>ORD00060</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>SAM</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>AAA1</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>2013</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>6</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>11</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>16</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>51</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>2013</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>6</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>11</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>8</td>
  <td class=3Dxl68 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none;box-sizing: bo=
rder-box;
  max-width:none'>26</td>
  <td class=3Dxl74>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=3Dxl65></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl73 style=3D'height:15.0pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl75 style=3D'height:15.0pt'></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
  <td class=3Dxl73></td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=3D0 style=3D'display:none'>
  <td width=3D119 style=3D'width:89pt'></td>
  <td width=3D69 style=3D'width:52pt'></td>
  <td width=3D82 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td width=3D70 style=3D'width:53pt'></td>
  <td width=3D53 style=3D'width:40pt'></td>
  <td width=3D70 style=3D'width:53pt'></td>
  <td width=3D62 style=3D'width:47pt'></td>
  <td width=3D82 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td width=3D69 style=3D'width:52pt'></td>
  <td width=3D63 style=3D'width:47pt'></td>
  <td width=3D83 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td width=3D83 style=3D'width:62pt'></td>
  <td width=3D95 style=3D'width:71pt'></td>
  <td width=3D78 style=3D'width:59pt'></td>
  <td width=3D84 style=3D'width:63pt'></td>
  <td width=3D98 style=3D'width:74pt'></td>
  <td width=3D98 style=3D'width:74pt'></td>
  <td width=3D109 style=3D'width:82pt'></td>
  <td width=3D167 style=3D'width:125pt'></td>
  <td width=3D112 style=3D'width:84pt'></td>
  <td width=3D112 style=3D'width:84pt'></td>
  <td width=3D64 style=3D'width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please give a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: I've added a picture of it, i want to match the creation date/time within 5 minutes and the account number ("oprano" in the call data AND "slaccount" in the order data).

Comment: Anything you can do to help would be amazing!!!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What is number of rows in both DataFrames?

Comment: Hi, can you maybe please also add why you don't/can't use `merge_asof` to match `orders_df` or haven't you tried that yet?

Comment: I cant use merge/join becuase I want to be able to specify that the call matches the order beween a range of minutes (within 5 minutes of the call). But struggling to make it work. Also the rows do not match, there will be a lot more calls than there are orders.

Comment: rows are 100,000's

Comment: I think for starters you should create a new column of `datetime` object by `df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["DAY","MONTH","YEAR", 'HOUR', 'MINUTE']])`. But again, please post sample data instead of posting links or ask us to execute code to get it.

Comment: I dont know how to it wont let me! everytime i paste it, it wants it to do it as an image? But i'm copying it straight from excel.

Comment: merge_asof  LOOKS AMAZING. Thank you!!! I think this will solve all my problems!